# Selenium Script on Startup

Tags: python, lxde, selenium, lxsession

I have a selenium script that I created to use Iceweasel.

It works fine if I run it manually. i.e. run the command myself.

When trying to get it to run on startup it does not seem to do a thing.

I have added the following line to `/etc/xdg/lxsession/LXDE-pi/autostart` and `/etc/xdg/lxsession/LXDE/autostart`:

`@python /home/pi/kiosk.py`

as well as `rc.local` and tried various other methods. I am starting to think maybe it is a permission thing or my command is wrong.

Answer (score 1):

There are various ways of running a command at startup, but you do need to make sure of certain things first:

- Check the permissions of your file, if you think they are correct, temporarily change them to 777 (`chmod 777 /path/to/script`) and try that
- Make sure the command/script works manually, which you have done
- Make sure that the command/script either runs in the background or exits quickly as most methods of running a command/script at startup require that the command/script exits before moving on to the next.

If none of these things help, you may want to look into `crontab`

You can edit `crontab` with:

```
sudo crontab -u pi -e
```

and add:

```
@reboot python /home/pi/kiosk.py
```

assuming your command/script exits, if your command/script is a long running one, there are many ways of putting it in the background. My personal favorite is running it in a `screen` so you can re-access it later. Just change that line to:

```
@reboot screen -d -m -S Kiosk python /home/pi/kiosk.py
```

Once your booted, you can check to see if your script is running by entering the command `screen -ls` and resume it by entering `screen -r Kiosk`, to leave the screen but leave it running hit Control A and Control D.

**EDIT**

I think I see your problem now. If you are trying to run a script that uses GUI at startup, there can be issues. The GUI doesn't start for a while after the boot, and almost all methods of running commands/scripts at boot runs them *almost* immediately. This means you will need a delay.

EX, for `crontab`

```
@reboot sleep 60; screen -d -m -S Kiosk python /home/pi/kiosk.py
```

This waits 60 seconds after the boot to run the script. You may need to wait longer or shorter depending on how fast your boot is. Time your boot and change the `60` to the appropriate time in seconds.

Comment: Will the `crontab` alternative run a GUI. As the selenium script opens a web browser and navigates.

Comment: `crontab` should run the command as if the user `pi` ran the command, but it runs it as soon as possible, so you will need to add a delay, I will update my answer

Comment: Does not seem to be working still. The pi definately does not take 1 minute to startup so 60 seconds is plenty of time. It may be an error in my script whilst running in this manner. Is there a way to export a verbose output from my script to a file?

Comment: Yep, `@reboot ... (blah blah) ... > /home/pi/Kiosk.log`

Comment: The log file was created but is empty, I am unsure where to go next

Comment: @MichaelSmith does your program have any output in the console when manually executed?

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackexchange.com/rooms/34519/discussion-between-patrick-cook-and-michael-smith).

Comment: @MichaelSmith Hi. Link to that discussion chat is not available. Did you solved your issue, I am on the same track. Can you please provide any help on this